# onkeypress function isn't defined despite being imported and within scope

Tags: php, html

I seem to have a problem with this code.

```
<td align = "right">Ingredients:</td> <td><textarea style="width: 300px" class="form-control" name="ingredients" rows="1" onkeypress='myFunction'></textarea></td>
```

I have imported it with require_once but despite me double checking for syntax errors, I can't get it to find the function. I get Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined. I have it in a block of code as such.

```
<?php
//some code I wrote

function myFunction() {
echo "hello";
}
?>
```

I tried this in google chrome and no matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to fire off. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

NOTE: I understand the responses so far but I am a bit confused as to why this didn't work yet in another .php file, they are all .php btw, I have this firing off correctly...

```
$recipe = Recipe::getRecipes( $dbh, true );
```

with the other .php file containing...

```
    class Recipe 
    {           
        function copyFromRow( $row ) { 
         // some code
        } 


        static function getRecipes( $dbh, $withnumbers=false ) { 
            //some if else statement
            return $result; 
        } 

        //more irrelevant code
     }
```

Now I am not sure if I am doing something differently between here and the first example, so could someone clarify on that please?

Comment: PHP runs on server side, JS runs on the client, you can't reach the php function directly, `php myFunction()` to `onkeypress='myFunction()'`, use ajax

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call directly PHP function on any [DOM Events](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp).

You should learn the use of [Ajax](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/),  [$.Post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

BTW, You can do this by using

**HTML**

```
<td align = "right">Ingredients:</td> <td><textarea style="width: 300px" class="form-control" name="ingredients" rows="1" onkeypress='myFunction()'></textarea></td>
```

**Ajax**

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'yourphpfile.php',
       data: {data:data}, // optional if wish to pass data
       success: function(response){
          console.log(response);
       }
    });
}
<script>
```

OR

**$.post**

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
     $.post( "yourphpfile.php", function( response ) {
       console.log(response);
     });
}
</script>
```

**yourphpfile.php**

```
 <?php
    if($_POST)
    {
       var_dump($_POST);
    }
  ?>
```

**Enjoy!**